# Is it possible to store all Unicode or UTF 8 digits in to a String?

Tags: java, encryption, hash, salt, utf-16

I am a CS student testing random generated salt value encryption, I tried to generate a salt through from a String data holder like:

String keychain = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjlxcvbnm,.][}{!@#$%^&*()";

However this is probably not efficient enough, so I was thinking that whether I would be possible that I could store an entire keyset like Unicode or UTF16 into a fixed String variable

Comment: Please explain how that keychain is not efficient enough, but the entire UTF8/16 is efficient enough?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know if String can hold any UTF-8 sequence? If so: yes, it can represent any valid Unicode strings (and a few invalid ones). Do you want a *single* `String`  that contains all possible Unicode values? If so: why, what are you trying to do with that? Most of the time a salt is meant to be `byte[]` (i.e. not text, but random binary data).

Comment: The UTF formats are structured, so cannot have the full randomness. But you can have a String with all Unicode values, _code points_. Simplest would be an `IntStream.ofRange(0, UNICODES)`.

Comment: So basically I'm worried that when generating a salt, the results could be limited due to the limited storage of String. The efficiency is not the code efficiency BTW

Comment: What do you mean by "limited storage of String"? What APIs are you using? Why are *you* generating a salt? Usually that's the job of the API.

Comment: Im an CS student working on a project where I store passwords onto a SQLdatabase, I', sorry that this question was poorly constructed.

Comment: Normally a salt is a byte array of random bytes. If you need to store it as a string you base64 encode the byte array for storage, base64 decode it when retrieving it to use it.

Comment: Basically I generate a random salt value by using the characters within a pre-declared String as shown above, but I think the salt generated could be limited, so I was thinking if I could use the UTF 8 or 16 character sets by either implementing all of the characters into the String variable, or access it through some other methods, I really should post my entire code.

Comment: You can select salt characters from a fixed string of length N. Just make sure your salt is at least K characters in length, where K >= (128 * log(2) / log(N)), and each character is selected using SecureRandom.nextInt(N). This will ensure your salt has at least 128 bits of entropy.

Comment: @JVAV_master: but why make up the salt of characters at all? Just do `byte[]`  and don't worry about what they represent anyway (since the salt has no "meaning"). And if you then need a `String` (for example because it's easier to store or something like that), then just use Base64 to turn that `byte[]` into a `String`.

Comment: When using secure random to generate salt somehow the salt value is always the same